# Fitting and scoring with training data doesn't get 100% accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I wanted to verify that if I tested my model with the same data that I trained it with it would give me an accuracy close to 100%, but that doesn't seem to be the case. (Or maybe this should just not be the case ?)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]

predict = "G3"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train,y_train)
accuracy = linear.score(x_train, y_train)

print(accuracy)
```

Comment: Please, provide full code. Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you will not see 100% accuracy. If you do, you've trained the model to ONLY detect the data exactly identical to what it trained on. The model will inevitably fail on predicting data it has not seen before, because it will not perfectly match what you trained it on. This is called overfitting. Your code sample is correct from reading it, though I don't have "student-mat.csv" to address the actual output.

Comment: @gallen The thing is, my accuracy is not even close to 100%, in fact it's basically the same accuracy as that which I get by fitting on train data and scoring of test data. (goes from 0.76 to 0.89)

Comment: That's actually very reasonable values. My point is, NEVER expect 100% accuracy, it will not happen. Try loading the Iris dataset from `sklearn.datasets` and running your same code above. It has "data" and "target" columns for your X, y respectively. The results you are getting are actually pretty good.

Comment: @gallen I get that 100% is not possible, but is it normal that testing with the train data doesn't show much higher accuracy than the regular case where you fit with training data and score with test data ?

Comment: @Noivy That depends entirely on the data itself. I recommend exploring with multiple data sets and seeing what happens to get a better understanding. Though I'm not certain why you would want to evaluate on test data to begin with. If you think your results are suspect, there is a process called Cross Fold Validation that will utilize the full data set in a series of folds to ensure your model is doing what you think.

Comment: @gallen As said on the main post, I just wanted to confirm that testing on the same data that I trained with would give very high accuracy. I will give the Cross Fold Validation a look, thank you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217103/discussion-between-noivy-and-gallen).

Answer (score 1):

With a model as constrained as LinearRegression, there's no reason to expect a perfect score on the training set.

You haven't given any details about your data, but note that you are using a regression model, whereas "accuracy" is a metric for classification models.  For `LinearRegression`, the `score` [by default is the R^2 value](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the proper metric. However, in OPs code, he is using the R^2 metric. `LinearRegression().score()` returns that value, he is just using a poorly named variable.